# How to launch gedit from terminal and detach it (just like "subl" command works)?

Tags: bash, background-process, gedit

To open a file to edit in gedit I run `gedit sample.py &`. But with Sublime Text it is simply `subl sample.py`. This opens the file to edit and it doesn't run in the background (in my shell).

How would I do that with gedit?

I tried `exec /usr/bin/gedit "$@"` (copied from `/usr/bin/subl`) but it works like `gedit &`.

Or `alias ged="gedit $file &"` should do. What can I substitute `$file` in the alias?

Comment: How did you install sublime?

Comment: @Wilf using apt-get  
`add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`
`apt-get install sublime-text-installer`

Comment: Aliases don't take parameters, apart from that your alias doesn't have a closing double quote (or is that a typo)

Comment: that was a typo..

Comment: Just want to know_when_ would one need to run an editor in the background?

Comment: I open lot of files at times. Shell  gets messy and I don't want to type `&` or  sometimes I forget to do that. And reaching  shift+7 takes some time you know :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
gedit() { /usr/bin/gedit $@ & disown ;}
```

It:

- Makes a function which can be called with `gedit`
- Launches `gedit` (using the full path `/usr/bin/gedit`), passing all the arguments/files given to it using `$@`
- `& disown` sends it to background and `disown` detaches it from the terminal/shell.

Comment: It works, great

Comment: ok :) you can add it to `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_aliases` or something if you want it to load into bash when it starts. Sorry I don't know how sublime text launches to the background as it looks like it is compiled, and as it isn't open source you can't guess from the source code.

Comment: yes added to .bashrc did that in first place :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a recent *GNOME 3* setup you could also use [`gapplication`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gapplication-tool.html)<sup>1</sup>:

```
gapplication launch org.gnome.gedit sample.py
```

to launch `gedit` just like you'd launch it from the dash (detached from terminal).
Sure, you can always define an alias:

```
alias ged='gapplication launch org.gnome.gedit'
```

or a function:

```
ged () { gapplication launch org.gnome.gedit "$@"; }
```

---

<sup>This only works for D-Bus activatable applications (run `gapplication list-apps` to get a list of apps).</sup>