# sh-4.4$ how to log back into my default shell terminal?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

When I open `gnome-terminal`, instead of presenting me with my default Bash shell, it shows:

```
sh-4.4$
```

This began happening since I added `DISPLAY=:0` to my `crontab -e` file which now looks as follows:

```
DISPLAY=:0

0 0,6,12,18 * * * /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/orschiro/bin/updates.sh
0 0,6,12,18 * * * /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/orschiro/bin/rclone.sh
```

And also of interest:

```
sh-4.4$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 18. Jun 10:30 /bin/sh -> bash
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `grep $(whoami) /etc/passwd` and `cat ~/.bashrc` using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This is your default bash shell. Probably you have tinkered with PS1 in .bashrc or .profile.

Comment: The only way I can think to get the string `sh-4.4` would be to have symlinked `bash` to `/bin/sh` (so that bash is invoked as `sh`, with the `-norc` switch) - you'd also need to have changed your terminal profile to use `/bin/sh` to observe this. Please check you terminal profile settings (in particular the "use custom command" settings) and add the output of `ls -l /bin/sh` to your question

Comment: OK so in that case it's probably not a change to your terminal profile, but the fact that the cron environment sets `SHELL=/bin/sh` - I still think you may have symlinked `/bin/sh` to `bash` for that to result in the prompt string `sh-4.4$` though (if `sh` were `dash` the default prompt would be a simple `$`)

Comment: I think you are right. See my edits. I am on Fedora 28. Maybe that's the default symlinked behaviour?

Comment: So, this isn't about Ubuntu at all then?

Comment: can you provide the result of the basic command $`whoami`?

Comment: The output of `$whoami` is empty.

Comment: I will experiment with something like this in my crontab: `0 0,6,12,18 * * * /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '/home/orschiro/bin/updates.sh';bash"
`

Comment: I don't see why your crontab would be relevant here. Please [edit] your question and show us i) the output of `ls -l /bin/bash` ii) what happens if you just run `bash` after opening the terminal and iii) the output of `echo $PS1`.

Comment: @orschiro The command is `whoami`, not `$whoami`.  The `$` that damadam used was supposed to represent the shell`s prompt.

Comment: Also, why, oh why, do you run the scripts _in a terminal emulator_ from your crontab. That's totally unnecessary.

Comment: Do these two scripts (attempt to) output content to your screen?

Comment: Why was this migrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the `gnome-terminal` started from your cronjob.

There is absolutely no need to run the cronjob scripts inside `gnome-terminal`. Doing so would mean that the jobs would fail if `gnome-terminal` could not be opened (which would probably happen if you weren't using the desktop at the time).

Just use

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * "$HOME"/bin/updates.sh
0 0,6,12,18 * * * "$HOME"/bin/rclone.sh
```

Any output from the scripts will be emailed to you, assuming local email delivery was enabled. To save the output to a log file, use a redirection:

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * "$HOME"/bin/updates.sh >>"$HOME"/updates.log"
0 0,6,12,18 * * * "$HOME"/bin/rclone.sh  >>"$HOME"/rclone.log"
```

The environment that the cronjobs are running in is different from the one you usually have when logged in through a graphical desktop environment. For one thing, your default shell may not be set in the `SHELL` environment variable, which is why `gnome-terminal` starts `/bin/sh` instead of `bash` (`sh` *is* `bash` on your system, but runs in POSIX compatibility mode when invoked as `sh`).

When logged in on the graphical desktop environment, opening `gnome-terminal` as usual would give you your default shell.  If it doesn't, it's because there's a `gnome-terminal-server` process running which was started by the cron jobs.  Terminate this process by either rebooting or by using `pkill -f gnome-terminal-server`.

See also [the comment posted by JdeBP below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453439/sh-4-4-how-to-log-back-into-my-default-shell-terminal/453443?noredirect=1#comment823811_453443).

Comment: Actually, no.  This does not get fixed without ensuring that the GNOME Terminal server process terminates.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333578/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132 for why it turns out that the mucking around with cron is important and why it is affecting all GNOME Terminals.

Comment: @JdeBP Urgh, it uses a server/client thingy. Well that sucks.  Ok, I'll update.