# Empty User Groups in Terminal Wrapper Applications

Tags: users, xterm

As of last Thursday, whenever I use any terminal (Konsole, Gnome Terminal, XFCE Termina, xterm), the `groups` are empty.

```
$ groups
tom
```

When I execute the same command in a `tty` terminal outside of Xorg, I get the correct groups:

```
$ groups
tom adm cdrom sudo plugdev docker libvirt
```

This is especially annoying since I now have to switch to a `tty` whenever I want to use docker. It happens when I use KDE, i3 or XFCE, it does not seem to happen when I switch to Gnome Shell (but that has other problems so I don't want to use it) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Has some setting changed or how can I get my user groups back?

**Addendum:**

Output of commands I've been asked to run via comments. **NOTE:** I've rebooted this system multiple times, in case that matters, and my OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

*xterm*

```
$ id -a
uid=1000(tom) gid=1000(tom) groups=1000(tom)
```

*tty*

```
$ id -a
uid=1000(tom) gid=1000(tom) groups=1000(tom),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),46(plugdev),134(docker),140(libvirt)
```

*xterm & tty - identical*

```
$ getent group | grep tom
adm:x:4:syslog,tom,mtail
cdrom:x:24:tom
sudo:x:27:tom
plugdev:x:46:tom
tom:x:1000:
docker:x:134:tom
libvirt:x:140:tom
```

*xterm & tty - identical*

```
$ type -f groups
groups is /usr/bin/groups
```

Comment: @slm I'm using this configuration on this machine for about 1.5 years now, and since day one the user `tom` was part of these groups. I also frequently reboot my device, as I am one of the last people who actually switch off their laptop at the end of the working day.

Comment: The last bit of advice I'd offer is to run this `strace groups tom` in tty & terminal and  compare them. I'm off to bed now.

Comment: One more - https://superuser.com/questions/294650/why-is-the-output-from-groups-different-from-groups-user-if-im-currently-log.

Comment: @slm I will do that, thanks for the help. Sleep well.

Comment: Three hints for slm and other potential answerers:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333578/5132, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132 , and Debian Bug #851243

Comment: As of this morning, the problem solved itself. I guess one update fixed a problem another update introduced. I don't know how to close this, there is no solution and I don't want to delete it in case someone finds the links helpful.