# Is a terminal emulator process a server?

Tags: terminal-emulator, netstat, lxterminal

Is a temrinal emulator process a server?

If yes, what is its client(s)? How can I find out its client(s)? Thanks.

1. `netstat` output contains lxterminal processes. Does that mean that
   a terminal emulator process is a server based on unix domain socket?

   ```
   $ sudo netstat -ap | grep -i lxterminal
   [sudo] password for t: 
   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     28665    1480/lxterminal      /run/user/1000/.lxterminal-socket-:0
   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28663    1480/lxterminal      
   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28661    1480/lxterminal      
   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28666    1480/lxterminal
   ```
2. A server is always (or usually?) a daemon, so it doesn't have a
   controlling terminal. lxterminal doesn't have one (`?`):

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep -i lxterminal
   t         1480  0.1  0.3 473204 28232 ?        Sl   Nov21  22:39 lxterminal
   ```

Comment: See answer to the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A X server is a server because it serves a display and input devices to applications.

Applications like `lxterminal` connect to that X server to request some service. For instance:

- *Please draw a Window of that shape and size*
- *Please tell me what key the user presses and releases*

They connect to the X server over a UNIX domain or ABSTRACT or TCP socket.

Similarly, the terminal emulator could be considered as a server for terminal applications.

With `echo test > /dev/pts/12`, the `echo` application can be seen as *connecting* to the terminal emulator (by way of a pseudo-terminal instead of a network socket, though here the *connection* is done by the shell redirection, not `echo`) and requesting a service: *please display test and move the cursor down*.

Now, some terminal emulators including gnome-terminal and lxterminal have that (annoying IMO) feature where on first invocation they start a daemon process that handles future requests to open new terminal window.

Later invocations of those connect to that server (using that `/run/user/1000/.lxterminal-socket-:0` UNIX domain socket in your case) to request a new terminal window, presumably to save resources or so that some information can be shared between terminal windows.

When you do:

```
cd /tmp && lxterminal -e vim
```

While there's already a `lxterminal` running, that second invocation just tells the `lxterminal` server  to run `vim` in a new window with the current directory changed to `/tmp`.

See `xterm` or `rxvt` for terminal emulators that work in a more conventional way.

You can actually do that same with:

```
printf '%s\0' /tmp lxterminal -e vim |
  socat -u - 'unix-connect:"/run/user/1000/.lxterminal-socket-:0"'
```

I find it annoying because that means only the first invocation inherits the environment (environment in the global sense, including `umask`, `cwd`, env vars...) of the caller, later invocations only get the cwd.

More on that in @JdeBP's fine answer at [lxterminal in the netstat output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333539)

Comment: Thanks.  In https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492752/674, is `/run/user/1000/.lxterminal-socket- type=STREAM` the socket that lxterminal uses for ensuring only one process running lxterminal?