# gnome-terminal do not start

Tags: linux-mint, gnome-terminal, locale

I faced the problem when terminal do not start. I have look at related issue when locale do not supported. I have tried to update it, regenerate it - nothing help. Finally I have found next error message in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Dec 31 00:45:43 kes-X751SA console-kit-daemon[2215]: (process:3545): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Dec 31 00:45:48 kes-X751SA org.gnome.Terminal[2464]: Locale not supported.
Dec 31 00:45:57 kes-X751SA console-kit-daemon[2215]: (process:3562): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Here is not clear. If I have wrong locale which locale is not supported??
How to check which locales are supported? How to apply supported locale?

Comment: `Locale not supported.` is not even an error. Real problem seems to be console kit.

Comment: Check if dbus is running

Comment: Do you have the Synaptics Package Manager or another?

Comment: @OmariCelestine: Yes, I have `Synaptic`

Comment: @jdwolf: `dbus` is running. [here](https://pastebin.com/B9yKteXz) is `ps ax|grep dbus`

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the "Troubleshooting" section of the *nosh Guide*, under the "GNOME Terminal refuses to start" heading:

> 

- The GNOME Terminal server requires that a UTF-8 locale be configured in its `LANG` environment variable, and refuses to start if it is not. It cannot be just the `C` locale.

Note that the GNOME Terminal server is the `org.gnome.Terminal` service started, indirectly via the DBUS Broker, under your per-user service manager.  It runs a program named `gnome-terminal-server` which is actually what provides the terminal emulator.  It is not the `gnome-terminal` *client* command that you are directly running, which is just a control program for that server.

- If you are letting the per-user/session DBUS broker spawn the server processes directly, which is the old but not recommended way of doing things, you need to ensure that your per-user/session DBUS broker is itself running in a UTF-8 locale.

  Since there are so many varied ways in which the DBUS broker can be invoked, exactly how you do this is beyond the scope of this answer.
- If your DBUS broker is simply passing things along to a proper per-user service manager, which is the new and now recommended way of doing things, you need to ensure that the service definition for your per-user `org.gnome.Terminal` service sets a UTF-8 locale.

  How you do this depends from what per-user service manager you have.  With nosh service management, for just one example, one just tweaks its service environment directory (`$HOME/.config/service-bundles/services/org.gnome.Terminal/service/env`) with the `set-service-env` command:

  ```
  system-control --user set-service-env org.gnome.Terminal LANG en_GB.UTF-8
  ```

  If you have systemd doing per-user service management, for another example, you'll need to inject an `Environment=` setting into `/lib/systemd/user/gnome-terminal-server.service` using the "drop-in" mechanism, which the systemd people do not document for per-user services.

You of course make sure that that locale actually exists as a locale definition on your system, too.  It is no good adjusting to UTF-8 locale if there is no such UTF-8 locale definition present.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). "Troubleshooting".  *[nosh Guide](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide.html)*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). "Per-user user services".  *[nosh Guide](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide.html)*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). "Demand starting per-user Desktop Bus user services".  *[nosh Guide](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide.html)*.  Softwares.
- Felix C. Stegerman (2014-04-29). *[gnome-terminal: will not start with non-utf-8 locale](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=746415)*.  Debian bug #746415.
- ["error constructing proxy..." when trying to launch gnome-terminal as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344617/)
- [Why do multiple instances of Mate-terminal have the same PID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226465/)
- [can't kill gedit process from its PID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323663/)
- [Why is a systemd user manager used in desktop sessions e.g. GNOME?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392912/)
- "[Exit status 8](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#Exit_status_8)".  *GNOME Terminal Frequently Asked Questions*. GNOME.

Comment: 1. Threre is no `*-server` process; 2. experimenting in `xterm` shows me exit status 9; 3. experimenting in `xterm` I set the `en_US.UTF-8` then manual run `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server` do not cause server appear in processes, also I get the `sys_page_size == 0` assertion in log; 4. I do not know which manager is used on my system. It is Linux Mint 18.1; 5. there is no `system-control` command on my system.; Thank you for detailed answer. I will check all your links soon.

Comment: Wellllll then. I stand corrected. Those error messages make completely no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of commands which helps me:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
reboot
```