# Can't load gnome-terminal on Debian Stretch, "Non UTF-8 locale is not supported!"

Tags: debian, gnome-terminal, locale

I've just completed a fresh install of Debian Stretch on a server that had previously been running Jessie, with `/home` preserved.

Now `gnome-terminal` fails to load.  Here's `syslog`:

```
18:29:02 alan dbus-daemon[918]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal'     nome-terminal-server.service'
18:29:02 alan systemd[899]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
18:29:02 alan gnome-terminal-server[4714]: Non UTF-8 locale (ANSI_X3.4-1968) is not supported!
18:29:02 alan systemd[899]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=8/     18:29:02 alan systemd[899]: Failed to start GNOME Terminal Server.
18:29:02 alan systemd[899]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
18:29:02 alan systemd[899]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
18:29:27 alan org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1003]: Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/    erminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
18:29:46 alan firefox-esr.desktop[1732]: Promise resolved while context is inactive
18:29:47 alan firefox-esr.desktop[1732]: Promise rejected after context unloaded: Message manager     ected
18:31:02 alan dbus-daemon[918]: Failed to activate service 'org.gnome.Terminal': timed out
```

I assumed that the non-UTF locale was the problem, and tried the following fixes based on googling:

Set `/etc/environment` to contain

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LCALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

Set `/etc/default/locale` to

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

and rebooted.  Locale now returns

```
root@alan:/etc# locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

but `gnome-terminal` still won't load.

Is this really a locale problem?  Where would `gnome-terminal` be getting its locale from?  What else could cause this?

Comment: LC_ALL= must maybe be defined as UTF-8 too ..  ll you need to do to fix this is regenerate the broken locale files. just do
sudo locale-gen
and check if the file
/etc/default/locale
has the following 2 definitions
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US"
or GB .... for you ... & this will be ok I think

Comment: I answered this once already at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413880/ . (-:

Answer (score 0):

Can you run (as root or sudo)...

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, no effect.