# Non x11 apps over x11

Tags: centos, x11, ssh-tunneling

I am seeing odd behavior on my X11 server on CentOS 6. X11 Forwarding works as you would expect. I can ssh (with `-Y` or `-X`) from CentOS 6 and launch & display `xclock`, but I can’t do the same for other applications like `gnome-terminal` or `gedit`—they just don’t display and their process is killed. The strangest part, is that if I connect into that same original CentOS 6 host from Windows first (via `Putty`) and use `Exceed` or `Xming` on Windows, I can then launch all applications without issue. So it seems to be an issue with the native X11 server on CentOS 6. If I turn verbose mode on for `ssh`, I do not get any errors, and X11 specific apps work just fine.

**Update**: this seems to only happen from a CentOS 6 machine to a CentOS 7 machine. Maybe there is a missing library on 6 to display the new graphics in 7?

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/344617/5132 again.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323700/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP Unfortunately, this doesn’t seem to matter. Please see the latest update to the question. Thanks