# Why does gedit only run with sudo?

Tags: gedit

```
$ which gedit
/usr/bin/gedit
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gedit
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 18696 Nov 27 05:55 /usr/bin/gedit
$ gedit
$ # Nothing happens
$ sudo gedit
[sudo] password for user:
$ # gedit window starts
$ # I close the gedit window
$ sudo chmod 0777 /usr/bin/gedit 
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gedit
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18696 Nov 27 05:55 /usr/bin/gedit
$ gedit
$ # Still nothing happens
$ uname -a
Linux linuxbox 5.4.8-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 6 16:44:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From a comment at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561507/how-to-find-out-why-gnome-extensions-fail), I learned that `journalctl --user` shows "[l]ogs for end user applications". Running that command, I see no references to `gedit`.

**Why is `gedit` only runnable with `sudo`?** I am already user `user` in the log above; I don't understand why it is necessary to do `sudo gedit` to run this executable.

---

**Update**: The context of this question is that I observed that clicking the `Text Editor` icon in my GNOME 3 desktop environment resulted in nothing happening. From some scrapping about, I discovered the `Text Editor` icon corresponded to the `gedit` executable. Thinking that I might have some diagnosable stderr by running `gedit` from a shell, I did so, and captured the corresponding log above.

Comment: Which user began the graphical session?

Comment: Probably https://askubuntu.com/a/270019

Comment: My thinking also.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323700/5132

Comment: @muru - if I understand the accepted answer at that link, the problem is if gedit has created config files _owned_ by `root` - but from the log I posted, when I type `sudo gedit` I am asked for `user`'s password - doesn't that mean the config files will be owned by `user`?

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen - As far as I'm aware, user `user`. I mean: I logged in as user `user`, and I originally clicked the `Text Editor` icon in my GNOME desktop environment, and found it failing. Some rummaging around, and I came to the understanding that the `Text Editor` icon corresponded to the `gedit` executable. I thought I'd have some form of diagnosable stderr by running `gedit` from a shell. Thus the log in the original post.

Comment: @StoneThrow `sudo` will always ask for the password of the user executing `sudo`. `sudo gedit` would ask for the current user's password, then start `gedit` as root. Files created by that `gedit` session would be owned by root. You may want to look at whether `gedit`'s configuration files on your non-privileged user's account are owned by root from having run `gedit` as root previously.

Comment: Never ever change permissions on, or ownership of, random executables on your system. Doing so could introduce serious security holes.  You can safely assume that the permissions and ownerships of files installed from a package manager are _correct_.

Comment: @Kusalananda - understood; thank you. Original file permissions restored.